# How does the iMac NVIDIA GeForce GTX 675MX compare to Desktop cards?

Tags: imac, games, gpu

I'm considering buying a new iMac and am wondering what the GTX675MX will do (have a hard time finding comparisons or tests with that).  I plan to use it for gaming (part with bootcamp/Windows7 if games not available for MacOS)

I think it's a mobile card and with the space restrictions it can't have the same power as (lets say) a PC GTX 670, so next to which PC GTX cards does it fall (I have a GTX 560 in PC for example which now tends to move towards falling down the cliff on the weak side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just theoretical, but according to the PassMark test, the 675MX should be about 30% faster than a desktop 560.  This is on the PC of course and some system specific may flow into the comparison, but at least there is a good chance that performance is at least a bit bettter than your GTX-560.

See [GTX 560](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/video_lookup.php?gpu=GeForce%20GTX%20560) vs. [GTX 675MX](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/video_lookup.php?gpu=GeForce%20GTX%20675MX)

Answer (score 2):

DO NOT GET the imac 680mx!!!! save and get 675mx same performance but with less cudas
1344 and 1 less gig of vram. Still running battfield 3 ultra 43fps 1440p
check this site http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1568279.